# Capturing the active control in an AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Using ASP.Net in a C# environment, I have the following code:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td width="15"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkUsers" runat="server" Text="" AutoPostBack = "True" oncheckedchange="chkUsers_OnCheckedChange" />
        </td>
        <td width="260">
            Active Users:
        </td>
        <td width="120">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboActiveUsers" runat="server" Height="19px" 
                AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="cboActiveUsers_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td width="15"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkAccount" runat="server" Text="" AutoPostBack = "True" oncheckedchange="chkAccount_OnCheckedChange" />
        </td>
        <td width="260">
            Account Name:
        </td>
        <td width="120">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboAccounts" runat="server" Height="19px" 
                AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="cboAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>N</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I'm trying to use the checkboxes as a toggle.  First of all, let me say the OnCheckedChange part never runs.  Not sure why.  Anyway, in my postback (in the code-behind) I'm trying to figure out which checkbox was the one that was just clicked, so I know which controls to enable and disable.  I want to say something like (obvious aircode):

```
If chkUsers is the checkbox that was just clicked
{
                cboActiveUsers.Enabled = true;
                ddlAuditor.Enabled = true;
                cboAccounts.Enabled = false;
}
If chkAccount is the checkbox that was just clicked
{
                cboActiveUsers.Enabled = false;
                ddlAuditor.Enabled = false;
                cboAccounts.Enabled = true;
}
```

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
protected void CheckboxStatus()
{
    if (chkAccount.Checked == true)
    {
        cboActiveUsers.Enabled = false;
        ddlAuditor.Enabled = false;
        cboAccounts.Enabled = true;
        chkUsers.Checked = false;

    }
    if (chkUsers.Checked == true)
    {
        cboActiveUsers.Enabled = true;
        ddlAuditor.Enabled = true;
        cboAccounts.Enabled = false;
        chkAccount.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

This works fine when chkAccount is checked, but when I go to toggle back it will only work if I first uncheck chkAccount.  Which makes perfect sense because that's the first checkbox it checks.  I want to just be able to click one or the other, back and forth, and have the enabled fields change accordingly.

Any takers?

ADD:  Here's my Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadSubjects();
        LoadStatusCodes();
    chkUsers.Checked = true;
    chkAccount.Checked = false;

    }
    CheckboxStatus();
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code in the `Page_Load` event?

Comment: @FelipeOriani - I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks fine, but in the `Page_Load` event, you should modify just on the first loa. I did some changes in your code, take a look on the comments bellow, for sample:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadSubjects();
        LoadStatusCodes();

        chkUsers.Checked = true;
        chkAccount.Checked = false;

        CheckboxStatus();
    }

    // here, every postback will execute
    // that's the reason you are getting every postback the called method
}

protected void chkUsers_OnCheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckboxStatus();
}

protected void cboAccounts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckboxStatus();
}

protected void CheckboxStatus()
{       
    if (chkAccount.Checked)
    {
        cboActiveUsers.Enabled = false;
        ddlAuditor.Enabled = false;
        cboAccounts.Enabled = true;
        chkUsers.Checked = false;
    }

    // you could do it.. to toogle the enabled controls, instead on in checked
    /* 
    cboActiveUsers.Enabled = !chkAccount.Checked;
    ddlAuditor.Enabled = !chkAccount.Checked;
    cboAccounts.Enabled = chkAccount.Checked;
    chkUsers.Checked = chkAccount.Checked;
    */

    if (chkUsers.Checked == true)
    {
       cboActiveUsers.Enabled = true;
       ddlAuditor.Enabled = true;
       cboAccounts.Enabled = false;
       chkAccount.Checked = false;
    }    

    /*
    cboActiveUsers.Enabled = chkUsers.Checked;
    ddlAuditor.Enabled = chkUsers.Checked;
    cboAccounts.Enabled = !chkUsers.Checked;
    chkAccount.Checked = !chkUsers.Checked;*/

}
```